# Renewing a still valid Canadian Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I have a valid Canadian Visitor Visa (multiple entry) on a passport that has been renewed.

My new passport is valid for 10 years and I would like to know if I can renew the unused Canadian Visitor Visa.

Comment: Do you mean transfer the visa to your new passport? Why do you want to renew the visa if it’s still valid?

Comment: the old valid visa is about 2.5 years still to expire, in renewing (if possible), i will be renewing with the new passport (which is 10 years valid)